# document.getElementById("").style.display='none'; is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to hide this login/register nav element when the user is logged in but it won't work.

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#banner" class="scrolly">Who are we</a></li>
                <li><a href="#main" class="scrolly">Our Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#features" class="scrolly">Our Story</a></li>
                <li><a href="#footer" class="scrolly">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Events</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="CurrentEvents.html" class="scrolly">Current Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#main" class="scrolly" id = "myevents">My Events</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Account</a>
            <ul>
                <li id = "Login/Register"><a href="LoginRegister.html" class="scrolly">Login/Register</a></li> 
                <li><a href="LoginRegister.html" class="scrolly" id = "userLoggedIn ">Abdalla</a></li>
                <li><a href="#footer" class="scrolly">Settings</a></li>
                <li id = "logout" onclick="logout()">Log out</li>
            </ul>
        </li>                       
    </ul>
</nav>
```

JS:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

    if (user) {
      document.getElementById("Login/Register").style.display='none';
    } else {
      document.getElementById("logout").style.display="none";
    }
  }
);
```

The function is getting called correctly, I tested it and 
I tried hiding other random elements such as the header and it worked. It just simply won't work with these nav elements. I tried other methods, I tried jQuery too, I tried removing the entire element and nothing happens. It's not returning NULL, its not giving me an error, but it simply won't work. Am I doing something wrong? Also, is this the proper way to do things when the user is logged in? just to hide certain elements? or is there a better way to do it. I am new to web dev and I am not sure whether this is the optimal way, so I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have multiple elements with the "Login/Register" id ?

Comment: console.log( document.getElementById("Login/Register") ) and see if the element is properly selecting. If multiple element with same id exists then this will show wrong selector

Comment: From what you've provided, it seams to be working fine, can you make sure all your ids are unique and that the `.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {` function is called correctly.

Comment: `user` could be faulsy. `undefined` for example.

Comment: Please check below scenarios: check if `onAuthStateChanged` method is getting executed, try to put 'console.log(user)' inside it, to sure if the user object is returning the correct value, then the last thing to check if document object is returning the ID you are specifying

Comment: I made sure that the id is unique, even put a random id there just to make sure, still same problem. I tried console.log( document.getElementById("Login/Register") ) and it does select the correct element. The function is correctly getting called and the user is correct. I tried hiding other elements such as ul and div and it works, but it won't work for li.

Comment: @Abdalla were you able to fix it? Can you provide an online demo?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to hide this login/register nav element when the user is
>   logged in but it won't work.

Are you sure you don't want this

```
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
   if (!user) {
     document.getElementById("Login/Register").style.display = '';
     document.getElementById("logout").style.display = "none";
   } else {
     document.getElementById("Login/Register").style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById("logout").style.display = "";
   }
 });
```